# Checking if the current date is greater than last monday

Tags: php, date

So basically what I am looking for is, how can I show the days that remain of this week until sunday, from current date and not show the passed days of the current week ? please point me in the right direction, I don't know where to start from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can return a numeric representation of the day of the week.

```
$current_date = (int)date('w');
```

Then you could walk through a loop outputing the remaining days.

Comment: finally a good answer... thank you sir ;)..I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`date(w)` will give you an day number ( 0 for sunday, 6 for saterday). [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo (7 - date("w")) ." days left before its sunday";
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what are you looking for ?

```
if (time() < strtotime('last monday')){
  //...
}
```

or you can divide them to get the day deference (how many days are passed)

like the following

```
$delta = time() - strtotime('last monday');
```

now you have the deference in seconds you can get from it the days

and for the value :

```
$number_of_days = (int)((time() - strtotime('last monday'))/(60 * 60 * 24)  );
```

today is Thursday and the output was 3 as [Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday]